# Issue with horizontal line in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm currently working on my CV and I'm using horizontal lines that I create via the `=== + Enter` shortcut.

However the issue is when I'm using bullet points and sub-bullet points, the horizontal line seems to bug and go beneath the sub-bullet point content:
[image: I want the horizontal line beneath the 3rd sub-bullet point to be gone]

Or like this:
[image: Another example]

Could you explain why it's appearing and how to remove it please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not a bug -- the line begins at the indent, as intended. To go back to the left margin, set that line as unnumbered, i.e., no level indentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Should I follow [these steps](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/adjust-indents-and-spacing-in-word-dd821599-b731-4c29-be3c-d854a705e086#ID0EBBD=macOS) ?

Comment: No, far too complex. Just put the horizontal line on a separate line, and use the <- icon to reduce *just that line's indent*. Unfortunately, MS Word may *also* try to reduce the indent of other lines, and it's a bit fiddly trying to get the appearance as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### These horizontal lines are paragraph borders, set to not have a border between paragraphs of the same style/formatting.

When you change the indent, you tell Word that this is a place for another border line. You should be able to select the paragraph and tell it (under the Borders and Shading menu) that you do not want any border.

For more, see [Troublesome Lines](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TroublesomeLines.htm#Borders) by Suzanne Barnhill, MVP

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You are welcome.